# Hatcher Proposition 1.32 (page 61)

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In the proof, I am unable to understand the statement **"The path-connectedness of $\tilde{X}$ implies that $\phi$ is surjective since $\tilde{x_0}$ can be joined to any point in $p^{-1}(x_0)$ by a path $\tilde{g}$ projecting to a loop $g$ at $x_0$".**

I imagine $X=S^1$ and $\tilde{X}$ as a helix winding around 3 times, so we have 3 cover sheets. Then $p_*(\pi_1( \tilde{X}, \tilde{x_0}))$ should be isomorphic to $3Z$. So, when we go once around the circle in $X$, we are moving from $\tilde{x_0}$ to the next point in $p^{-1}(x_0)$ in the helix (covering space). How are the points in $p^{-1}(x_0)$ being path-connected proving that the map $\phi$ is surjective?

Comment: As @J.Doe says, you should include context instead of forcing readers to look up what you're talking about. In your case, you're talking about the map $\Phi$ from right cosets of $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0))$ in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ to the fiber $p^{-1}(x_0)$. To answer your question, points in $p^{-1}(x_0)$ have paths between them because $\tilde{X}$ is path-connected ... that's what path-connected *means*, no?

Comment: If you label the elements of $p^{-1}(x_0)$ in order as $a,b,c$ when $\tilde{X}=S^1$ then going around $X=S^1$ once takes us from $a$ to $b$, going around it twice takes us from $a$ to $c$, and so the map is surjective.

Comment: @arctictern: Thanks for the explanation. But I think the map $\phi$ takes us to the **end-points** of the curve. So, once around circle in X, takes us to b, twice around to c and so on and so forth. I think later the map $\phi$ is also shown to be injective, and therefore I think $\phi$ is actually a bijective map right?

Comment: Yes. It's basically the orbit-stabilizer theorem: if $G$ acts on a set $X$ with and a point's stabilizer is ${\rm Stab}(x)$ then $G/{\rm Stab}(x)\to{\rm Orb}(x)$ given by $g{\rm Stab}(x)\mapsto gx$ is a bijection (not to mention $G$-equivariant).

Comment: @arctictern: Thanks. I will look into the orbit-stabilizer theorem to understand this better. Is there a good book you recommend for this? Or Dummit and Foote is good enough for this?

Comment: OS is a standard fact covered in most group theory courses (albeit at the end of some). There should be numerous good sources that are easily accessible just through googling.

Answer (score 1):

Here for covering space $p:\tilde X \rightarrow X$  with $H=p_*(\pi_1(\tilde X, \tilde x_0))$ we define $\phi:\{H[g]: [g] \in \pi_1(X,x_0)\} \rightarrow p^{-1}(x_0)$ by $\phi(H[g]) = \tilde g(1)$ as did Hatcher. To show surjectivity suppose $x\in p^{-1}(x_0)$. As $\tilde X$ is path connected we can create a path $\tilde \gamma:I \rightarrow \tilde X$ such that $\tilde \gamma(0) = \tilde x_0, \tilde \gamma(1) = x$. Further, as $p(\gamma(0))= p(\gamma(1)) = x_0$, $p \circ \tilde \gamma$ is a loop in $X$ call it $\gamma$. Thus we choose $\gamma$ and have $\phi(H[\gamma]) = \tilde \gamma(1) = x$. Thus $\phi$ is surjective.